# Return ref_cursor from for loop of cursor object

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, sys-refcursor

I am trying to get a ref_cursor to be assigned to a variable inside a for loop then returned at the end of a function. The loop in going through a local cursor if it gets more than 1 result.

I have noted where the error occurs in the code. I am not sure how to create a loop where i can get a ref_cursor for the current point in the loop, assign it to a variable and then return it to the function. Could someone someone help me figure out how to do that? Below is my i-th attempt at logic based of reading around the google searches.

The error is "PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type" and i know that i obviously am not assigning the correct variably type based on this error but the code below with the error is an illustration of what I want to do and what I need help accomplishing.

```
FUNCTION GET_PARCEL(p_lat in number, p_long in number) return sys_refcursor 
IS
  v_distance number(10) := 100000000;
  v_shortest_dist number(10) := v_distance;
  v_centroid SDO_GEOMETRY;
  v_rc_ref_cursor sys_refcursor;
  v_ref_geom SDO_GEOMETRY :=  mdsys.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8311, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(120.3214, -10.7088));
  cursor query_cursor is select * from PARCEL_TABLE where code = 20134;
BEGIN
  for query_row in query_cursor loop
            v_centroid := SDO_GEOM.SDO_CENTROID(query_row.geometry, 0.05);
            IF (v_centroid is not null) then    
                v_distance := SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(v_centroid, v_ref_geom, 0.05);
                IF v_distance < v_shortest_dist THEN
                    v_shortest_dist := v_distance;
                    v_rc_ref_cursor := query_row; -- Error on this line
                END IF;
            ELSE
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Centroid is not initialised for some reason.');
            END IF; 
  end loop;

  return v_rc_ref_cursor;
END;
```

Comment: Only one question. What is interact_row? You should put query_row instead of interact_row. Shouldn't you ? Excuse me, I have a mistake. I think you should assign to v_rc_ref_cursor a cursor. So you must write: v_rc_ref_cursor := query_cursor;

Comment: Corrected the typo @AlexisSTDM and everything still stands as before

Comment: If I give it the value of query_cursor then it will have multiple results. I want my ref_cursor to be pointing at a specific point of my cursor traversal so I return just one result.

Comment: Are you trying to return a single row, or everything from the point you find the shorter distance?

Comment: @AlexPoole Just a single row. I want the loop to go through every result and then only return a ref_cursor for the single result with the shortest distance from my reference point.

Comment: So why are you returning a cursor, rather than just a row - can you create an object type (or record type, depending on where this will be consumed) and return that instead? A ref cursor for a single row seems like an odd way to approach this.

Comment: That was the original approach I wanted to take however the business requirement is a ref_cursor needs to be returned.

Comment: I think you need to return all the cursor for solving the type match error, and you will have all the cursor, the data and the status. So, after calling the function, when you would fetch a row, you will get the next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pro tip is to remember you have data in your table and you can use it for logic. Turns out if I use the IDENTIFIER or ROWID of the row/s which i want then i can do a where clause into a ref cursor that looks up by IDENTIFIER or ROWID.

eg.

```
open v_rc_ref_cursor for select * from PARCEL_TABLE n where n.identifier = query_row.identifier;
```

super simple stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot build up a cursor.  Cursors are created and maintained by the database with connections to their source data, transaction and session context, and the like.

I would suggest you declare a type, instantiate it, build up the values in the type.

When you are done, create a cursor by selecting * from table (cast (variable as your_type)).

Munge the cursor into a ref_cursor and return that.